# How to pass tkinter Entry values to a function in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to pass the values in a tkinter Entry box to a function without using a button. How can I so this?

I've tried just binding the Entry field but what is passed is not the entry but a KeyPress Event

```
import tkinter


def print_entry(entry):
    print(entry)

root = tkinter.Tk()
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry_field.pack()
entry_field.bind("<Return>", print_entry)
entry_field.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

I expect to get the values entered in the Entry box but instead get:

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod1 keysym=Return keycode=13 char='\r' x=966 y=186>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a solution:

```
import tkinter


def print_entry(entry):
    print(entry)


root = tkinter.Tk()
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry_field.pack()
entry_field.bind("<Return>", lambda x: print_entry(entry_field.get()))
entry_field.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you bind a function, the function will be passed an argument which represents the event. One of the attributes of that argument is `widget`, which represents the widget that received the event.

The most common solution is to *not* pass values into callbacks. Instead, have the callbacks retrieve the information that they need using this object:

```
def print_entry(event):
    print(event.widget.get())
```